# IT project Management

Tags: work-environment

If the workload of resigned person is assigned to another person in the same project what happens to the workload of the person? Explain a technique to resolve the aforementioned issue. Can I have an answer for this question

Comment: Have you asked your boss on how this should be managed? Or is this call up to you to decide and this have no one to consult with?

Comment: @DarkCygnus this is a homework dump, and not a real workplace question, so they have no boss to ask

Answer (score 3):

> If the workload of resigned person is assigned to another person in
>   the same project what happens to the workload of the person?

Sometimes the other person handles both workloads.

Sometimes the other person's original workload is passed on to yet another worker.

Most often, the other person picks up some of the new workload and drops some tasks that were optional and don't need to be done.

All this is at the discretion of the manager. If you want to know what is expected of you - ask your boss. Nobody here can predict what will happen in your case.

Comment: yes, it's up to management.